# I want to change the select icon/dropdown icon to (fa-chevron-down). How can I?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to use a form like in the code is from bootstrap but i want to change the select icon/dropdown icon to `fa-chevron-down`.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Some-text</label>
        <select class="form-control input-lg">...</select>
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Some-text</label>
        <select class="form-control input-lg">...</select>
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Some-text</label>
        <select class="form-control input-lg">...</select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you mean checkbox?

Comment: It's already a chevron

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses font-awesome's [`fa-chevron-down`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/chevron-down/) natively (without using an image). It does require that you add a font-awesome tag to your markup, but it's fairly clean.

```css
/* remove the original arrow */
select.input-lg {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  /* no standardized syntax available, no ie-friendly solution available */
}

select + i.fa {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* this is so when you click on the chevron, your click actually goes on the dropdown menu */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* everything after this is just to cover up the original arrow */
  /* (for browsers that don't support the syntax used above) */
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Some-text</label>
        <select class="form-control input-lg">
          <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Some-text</label>
        <select class="form-control input-lg">
          <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Some-text</label>
        <select class="form-control input-lg">
          <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's filthy and it seems I like it, BTW it is of course also possible without Bootstrap and some fiddling.

Comment: @jpoppe well, the "filthy" stuff (using a white background to cover up the native arrow) is only necessary for internet explorer / edge.

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution based in the solution above (Woodrow Barlow), with light improvements

```css
    /* remove the original arrow */
    select{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -o-appearance: none;
        appearance: none; 
        background-color: #92ceea!important;
     }

    select::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
    }

    select + i.fa {
        float: right;
        margin-top: -26px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        /* this is so when you click on the chevron, your click actually goes on the dropdown menu */
        pointer-events: none;
        /* everything after this is just to cover up the original arrow */
        /* (for browsers that don't support the syntax used above) */
        background-color: transparent;
        color:black!important;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

   select option{
       padding-right: 21px;
   }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<select class="form-control">
        <option value="">select_option</option>

        <option value="1">Opção1</option>
        <option value="2">Opção2</option>
</select>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
```

**Browser compability**
Safari 5.1.7   |  IE9    |   Firefox   |   Google Chrome

**Note**
In IE9 fa arrow is in front

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a CSS file (that you link in the head part of the page) and to specify for this class a background image :

```
.row > .col-sm-6 > form-group > .form-control-input-lg
{
  background: url(images/example.gif) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px;
  padding-left:0px;
}
```

This css wil add a background with your image and after you only have to modify the padding and the position of the background by the ones you want to have the glyphicon in your control.