# Adding Font Awesome icon to Bootstrap 4 select

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to add [this icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/angle-down/) to a simple Bootstrap 4 select. So it looks more like a dropdown. How can I do this?

This is my code so far:

```css
.custom-select {
  background-color: #009CFF;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <select class="custom-select rounded-0 border-0">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The snippet is for some reason not showing changes as my editor is. So here, have it in [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrMKgV) version too. Anyway, I've tried adding it in like this, too, but it's not working:

```
.custom-select:after {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: If that is the icon, why the style is `content: "\25AE";` and not `content: "\f107 ";`?

Comment: like this : https://jsfiddle.net/m5ucsneo/1/

Comment: @AlonEitan Wrong content, sorry. But it doesn't really matter, as long as it works, I can change the content icon.

Comment: @MinarMnr I don't understand? Where does the font awesome icon go?

Comment: I know you prefer a Font Awesome solution, but given that `.custom-select` creates this icon via `background-image` have you considered a similar approach?  Using pseudo classes doesn't seem to solve the issue, I assume because of how Bootstrap handles the customizations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to change the select icon/dropdown icon to (fa-chevron-down). How can I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646923/i-want-to-change-the-select-icon-dropdown-icon-to-fa-chevron-down-how-can-i)

Comment: check this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646923/i-want-to-change-the-select-icon-dropdown-icon-to-fa-chevron-down-how-can-i

Comment: @RobertC That's a good idea, actually! Thank you! Let's see if I can style it properly. Lol!

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you are looking for [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/).

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <select id="mySelect" data-show-content="true" class="form-control">
                <option>Select..</option>
                <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-cutlery'></i> Cutlery"></option>
                <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Eye"></option>
                <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-heart-o'></i> Heart"></option>
                <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-leaf'></i> Leaf"></option>
                <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-music'></i> Music"></option>
                <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-star'></i> Star"></option>
                <option data-content="<span class='badge badge-warning mt-1 ml-2 float-right'>3</span> More"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#mySelect').selectpicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41574046/171456) it's *not* possible to style a HTML select element, and that includes using pseudo `:after` and `:before`.