# How do i set font awesome icon on select dropdown?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, font-awesome, dropdown

I want to set font awesome icon on select drop down and change the background color as well... I tried this code but it won't be work..

**Here is my CSS code:**

```
select {
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 0px 70px 1px 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  box-shadow: 10px 3px 8px #888888;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;
}
select i {
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  background-color: orange;
  bottom: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Here is my HTML Code:**

```
<div class="row">
      <p class="search">Search by Location</p>
      <select class="dropdown">
           <option>Canada</option>
      </select>
      <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: did you put the fontawesome css in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: no, i just put after select tag

Comment: put it before select, otherwise it will load select first and then css, so it won't work.

Comment: What kind of Font Awesome are you using. If you're using the CSS CDN, it should go in your `<head>`; if you're using a JavaScript kit, it should go at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: Just a heads up, `<select>` elements with nested `<option>` elements by default have a chevron down arrow included already.

Comment: I recommend that you avoid styling input elements too much, because iOS will **completely ignore** certain styles, which will lead to inconsistent styling across browsers.

Comment: check this Answer hope this will work for you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53664264/10079978

Comment: @FelipeMoreira I tried to put before select tag... just arrow goes to left side...it won't be work

Comment: is why `<select>` already has a standard icon.

Comment: @DaemonBeast I am using kit font awesome CDN not css CDN...

Comment: @FelipeMoreira I want styling that arrow like background color and arrow will go to in radius

Comment: Your CSS doesn't make sense. You're styling any `<i>` elements inside of `<select>` elements, but that doesn't match your HTML. Did you mean to use `select + i`?

Comment: @DaemonBeast i is user for defining icon

Comment: The `i` won't get styled though, because your CSS is styling `i` elements INSIDE `select` elements, but in your HTML, the `i` element is after the `select` element. `select + i` should be used if you want to style `i` elements directly after `select` elements.

Comment: hi   @vasudevu you can simply try  to add  color: orange;     to your select style  it will give you orange color for both Canada  and the select arrow

Comment: @abdelhak51 but the point is arrow doesn't come on dropdown

Comment: @devanshi  the code  is working fine for me the arrow is inside the select

Answer (score 0):

Edited Answer

```
select.input-lg {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  /* no standardized syntax available, no ie-friendly solution available */
}

select + i.fa {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* this is so when you click on the chevron, your click actually goes on the dropdown menu */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* everything after this is just to cover up the original arrow */
  /* (for browsers that don't support the syntax used above) */
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Source: [I want to change the select icon/dropdown icon to (fa-chevron-down). How can I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646923/i-want-to-change-the-select-icon-dropdown-icon-to-fa-chevron-down-how-can-i)

Also you may follow this: [font awesome icon in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If i remove below line then how arrow will come on dropdown?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Vasudevu/pen/wvMrmgP   In codepen showing original dropdown and i don't able to change css of <i>

Comment: just remove and test it. Its already showing dropdown arrow.

Comment: I checked there in codepen appearance:none; css property not working... that's why it shows correct... I want to remove that arrow and put icon and set background color and radius in that...

Comment: Please go through the source link I have given, it will definetly will resolve your all issues regarding "select icon change"

Comment: I tried your source link but not getting actual output

Comment: It may be issue with your font awsome lib because its not visible in output. please try to provide the actual location where you are running this.

Answer (score 0):

For his code and a fontawesome solution

```
.row select {    
    display: inline-block;
    appearance: none;
    margin-right: -24px;
    padding-right: 36px;
}
.row i {
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

worked for me.